# Can Mono create/run reports in rdlc?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, rdlc

I've never used mono and was curious if mono can create/run rdlc reports? What I'm looking at implenenting is a mono asp.net mvc app to use a rdlc to create a report and export to pdf. Is this possible with mono?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some open source projects which tried to implement RDL reporting in .NET:

- NReports: http://nreports.codeplex.com/
- fyiReporting RDL Project: http://fyireporting.com/index.html
- ReportFu: http://reportfu.org/
- ReportingCloud: http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportingcloud/