# Qt equivalent for Microsoft's ReportViewer

Tags: qt, reportviewer

Is there a Qt equivalent for Microsoft Report Viewer (something that would work not only on windows but on linux and osx, too)? So, some Qt component for designing and printing reports.

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8336936/298573, it's for .net but at least it's open source.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting...I didn't know that there are some open source report viewer alternatives. Anyway, I need something for Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found at the end: http://www.nocisoft.com/ncreport.html